# What does this flag declined comment mean?

Tags: support

This is quite old, but I just found it today while going through the flagged posts. I cannot understand what this comment on the flag decline means.

[image: flag declined]

When I saw at this question, it had 4 close votes, so I flagged the question because I honestly felt it should not be closed. I have also mentioned this clearly in my comment along with the reason.

The reviewer (diamond moderator, I presume) declined my flag and asked me to "vote to close" instead in the future.

What exactly is this supposed to mean? If I believe that a question should not be closed, then I should vote to close anyway?

Comment: Someone probably misread your flag. Let me check it out for you.

Comment: If the question had 4 VTC and you feel it should be left open, you should go to the review queue and vote to leave it open. If three people (I think) vote for a question to be left open, those votes will go away. Also, I believe that is the only way for the votes to go away (other than the question being closed). Although I can't answer for this flag review in particular, in the future you should do what I described above, rather than flagging the post. Especially because I think not even mods can clear those votes (presuming that is why you flagged it for moderator attention).

Comment: @JNat Yeah, that makes sense. The response given to the flag decline was confusing. I will do that in future.

Comment: It isn't a big issue, but I want to point out that close votes review is only available to users with X reputation. While I did have the required X reputation, but at that time, it did not occur to me that I could use the close votes review. Nonetheless, someone without the X reputation won't be able to use this method. (Not complaining about it, this is how the site design works, which in many ways is a good thing.)

Comment: @JNat The votes only go away after a fairly long period of time, on the order of several days. If the question is already at 4 votes to close, it's probably too late to try to get them to expire. I'd conjecture that it would be more effective to leave a comment or start a meta post related to the closing of the question. Also, mods do have at least one way of clearing close votes on a question, by closing and then reopening it. That's not ideal but I've seen it used in cases like this on other sites.

Comment: @LoganM You're right. But that period is reduced once three people vote to leave the question open. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/208518).

Comment: @JNat Yes, I'm aware of that. However, even with removal from the queue and accelerated aging, I think that questions with 4 close votes are very likely to get a fifth before the first one ages away.

Comment: @Happy I declined that flag. I guess I probably misread the flag and was confused in why you wanted to flag it. I didn't think there was any need to initiate any action so I declined it. I probably meant to say that you should vote to close/reopen in the future instead of flagging it.